# What is the most efficient bway to get len of string ?

Tags: c, runtime

A lot of people wrote that this version of `get_len` is faster :

```
int get_len(char* str)
{
    char *cpy;

    cpy = str;
    while (*cpy)
    {
        ++cpy;
    }
    return (cpy - str);
}
```

than this one :

```
int get_len2(char* str)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i])
    {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

But when I check the run time, The second one seems faster...

So my question is why ??

here's the main function test:

```
int main()
{
    clock_t begin, end;
    double time_spent;

    begin = clock();

    printf("%d\n", get_len("HEEEEY"));

    end = clock();

    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("%f\n", time_spent);

    begin = clock();
    printf("%d\n", get_len2("HEEEEY"));
    end = clock();

    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("%f", time_spent);

    return 0;
}
```

The output :

```
6
0.000025
6
0.000001%
```

Comment: I'd say it's absolutely indifferent... Also, one sample is not a sample, call those functions at least several thousands of times.

Comment: If you are not limiting the comparing to these two, check out how glibc implements `strlen`, which has a remarkable performance.

Comment: OT: You'd better use `size_t` but `int` as it's guaranted to be wide enough to represent any possible "length". Also the pointer passed into should better be declared `const char *`.

Comment: Where is this written?

Comment: @meaning-matters: You might like to look it up in the C standard. I'm sure it 's in there. With the limititation to what is possible for the target system of course!

Comment: @alk Nice things like this are in the standard.

Comment: Your benchmark code is not useful. You are trying to measure a __single__ call to a tiny function _and_ including the time taken by `printf`.

Comment: If you like my answer, please select it :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These functions are so similar that you can't say which one is faster in general.

It all depends on compiler, its options, and processor you run it on.

But it's probably because `str[i]` expands to `*(str + i)`. Hence you get one additional `+` operation in your `get_len2()`. But again, a smart compiler will rip code like this apart, and reconstruct it in totally different ways in assembly.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to run this test many times over many strings of different lengths before you would get any useful statistics.

Since an array access `a[j]` is interpreted as `*(a + j)`, the expectation is that a straight dereference such as in the first example should be faster than a subscript operation, which involves an addition as well as a dereference.

This assumes that the compiler doesn't do any optimization, or that it does a naive translation of the expression, which may not be true.

Again, the only way to know for sure is to run both versions against many strings of many different lengths.  Then it's a question of whether either version buys you anything over just using the `strlen` library function (short answer: it won't).

Answer (score 2):

**Iterations are faster with arrays compared with pointers** (though i'm not confident, I read it from some articles,just trying to give you some idea on it ). Pointers are best in case of insertions and deletions, As in your program you are just iterating, array usage resulted in lesser iteration times.

One of the link i referred:
Please go through the first and second comments in this link http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/99899-pointer-vs-array-speed/

Answer (score 2):

There are probably several good reasons why the following code is slower:

```
int get_len(char* str)
{
    char *cpy; 

    cpy = str;          // does a copy of a parameter value, not necessary
    while (*cpy)
    {
        ++cpy;
    }
    return (cpy - str); // does pointer arithmetic, valid but slow
}
```

Compare to the following annotated code:

```
int get_len2(char* str)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;             // should be one quick instruction
    while (str[i])     // same as str+i
    {
        i++;
    }
    return i;          // no pointer arithmetic
}
```

Try benchmarking the following code (caution, I haven't compiled or tested it myself):

```
int get_lena(char* str)
    {
        int i = 0;    // a string of only "\0" has length zero
        while (*str++) {i++;}
        return i;
    }
```